# FLOSS screenshot/generic file uploader for Linux (ShareX replacement)

Tags: linux, open-source, screenshot, cloud-storage

On Windows, I use ShareX. I'm looking for a piece of free software for Linux that can do these things.

- Take screenshots of the current monitor, current window, all monitors or a custom rectangular area.
- Automatically upload files to a custom web service and store the URL to the file in the clipboard.
- There should be a possibility to assign keyboard shortcuts to perform all of the above at once.
- Ideally, it would support uploading files copied to the clipboard as well.

Using my current setup on Windows, I can press the Print Screen key and ShareX will take a screenshot of the current monitor, save it locally, and automatically upload it to a "custom file uploader". I configured it to upload it to a web application using a simple POST request and some authentication credentials. It then extracts the URL from the response using a regular expression (actually, the application returns JSON, but ShareX doesn't seem to support that - I wouldn't mind JSON support) and stores it in the clipboard.

Basically, I'm looking to replicate that functionality on Linux. Is there a free software tool for Linux that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

**[Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/)** matches this fine (also see [these answers](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=shutter+is%3Aanswer+[linux])):

- **Take screenshots of the current monitor, current window, all monitors or a custom rectangular area:** Yes. Additionally of menus, including/excluding the mouse pointer, configuratble delay.
- **Automatically upload files to a custom web service and store the URL to the file in the clipboard:** Yes. Multiple services pre-configured (e.g. Imgur), additional places via FTP or plugins
- **There should be a possibility to assign keyboard shortcuts to perform all of the above at once:** Indirectly. See [configuring hotkeys](http://shutter-project.org/faq-help/set-shutter-as-the-default-screenshot-tool/) and the [Man Page](http://shutter-project.org/faq-help/man-page/). Combined actions should be possible via scripting, but I've not tested that.
- **Ideally, it would support uploading files copied to the clipboard as well:** I've not figured whether that's possible.

*Shutter* is free and open-source. I'm using it for years and am pretty satisfied – especially for the edit functionality, which not only lets me crop images, but also add arrows, text boxes and more (very useful for tutorials and the like).

Comment: Thanks. I wrote a upload plugin which seems to work, but I can't figure out how to get Shutter to automatically upload the image when I press my hotkeys. There seems to be an [open feature request](https://bugs.launchpad.net/shutter/+bug/585197) for this, but it hasn't been implemented since 2010. You said it could be done via scripting, do you happen to have any hints on that?

Comment: Not more than the linked pages give. I've never tried it myself, being content with what the app offers as it is. Afraid with this part you need to confront the devs.There's even [a link for that](http://shutter-project.org/contact/) on their dev page;)